# Why in this code i am getting Lexical error is coming using javacc tool

Tags: javacc

I have made a AssignStatement class and i am trying to pass the String using javacc.
The assignment statement is of the form :a=b+c*d.
Here, is the Source Code

```
options

{

static=false;
DEBUG_TOKEN_MANAGER=true;
}
public class AssignStatement
 {      
public static void main(String s[])
 {
 try
  {
    AssignStatement as=new AssignStatement(System.in);
    as.StartSymbol();
    System.out.println("Syntax checking successfully");
  }

 catch(Throwable e)

 {
  System.out.println("Syntex checking failed"+e.getMessage());
 }
}
}

PARSER_END(AssignStatement)

SKIP: {"" | "\t" | "\n" | "\r" }
TOKEN:{ "(" | ")" | "+" | "*" | ":=" | <NUM:(["0"-"9"])+>|   <ID:(["a"-"z"])+> }

   void StartSymbol(): {}
  { 
   (AStmt())*<EOF>
  }

  void AStmt(): {}
 { 
   LOOKAHEAD(2) <ID> "=" AStmt() 
   | Term() ("+" Term())*
 }

   void Term(): {}
 {
   Factor() ("*" Factor())*
 } 

   void Factor(): {}
 {
   <NUM> 
   | <ID> 
   | "(" AStmt() ")"
 }
```

The Output i got after i did java AssignStatement

"a=10+20*30"

Current character : \" (34) at line 1 column 1
   No string literal matches possible.
   Starting NFA to match one of : { ,  }
Current character : \" (34) at line 1 column 1
Syntex checking failedLexical error at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: "\"" (34)
, after : ""

Output I should get

syntex checked successfully.

Comment: Are the double quote characters `"` part of the input?

Comment: The production for `ID` is no good, as it is completely subsumed by the production for `NUM`.

Comment: With your edit to `ID`, the code works. For example `Reader reader = new StringReader( "a=10+20*30" ) ; AssignStatement as=new AssignStatement(reader); as.StartSymbol();` throws no errors. Note that there is still a serious problem owing to the regular expression that matches the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

The first character of the input is `"`, but there is no regular expression that allows the first character to be a `"`. So the lexer throws a TokenManagerError after reading the first character.

Comment: NO it is not part of input sir.It is used to denote we take String as argument.

Comment: Well that's very strange, because the error message starts with `Current character : \" (34) at` which suggests that the character is number 34, which is the double quote.  However I will edit my answer.

Comment: On second thought I'm not changing my answer.